# nativeElement select wait for binding data

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's say that I have a child component called `inputComponent` that has a single input element as follow

```
@Component({ template: `<input #count [(ngModel)]="item.count" />`})
export class inputComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input item;
    @ViewChild("count") count : ElementRef ; 


    focus(){
       this.count.nativeElement.focus();
       this.count.nativeElement.select();
    }

 }
```

and I'm including it in a parent container as follow

```
<app-input-component [item]="item" ></app-input-component>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to select the text input on a certain event.
for example

```
@ViewChild("input") count : inputComponent ; 
foo(){
this.item = item ; 
this.count.focus();
}
```

The problem is when I call focus change right after changing the binding data (item) it doesn't select anything hover if I called `focus()` after a short timeout it works perfectly .

I know it's not the proper way to use `setTimeOut` to solve it.

Stackblitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svgmtg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `ngModel` updates the view's value **asynchronously** when the model is changed. I.e. the `<input>` value is not changed until the next change detection cycle!

From the `ngModel` [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L29-L46):

````
/**
 * `ngModel` forces an additional change detection run when its inputs change:
 * E.g.:
 * ```
 * <div>{{myModel.valid}}</div>
 * <input [(ngModel)]="myValue" #myModel="ngModel">
 * ```
 * I.e. `ngModel` can export itself on the element and then be used in the template.
 * Normally, this would result in expressions before the `input` that use the exported directive
 * to have and old value as they have been
 * dirty checked before. As this is a very common case for `ngModel`, we added this second change
 * detection run.
 *
 * Notes:
 * - this is just one extra run no matter how many `ngModel` have been changed.
 * - this is a general problem when using `exportAs` for directives!
 */
const resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve(null);
````

Then when the model is updated, the view is [updated asynchronously](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L323-L326):

```
private _updateValue(value: any): void {
  resolvedPromise.then(
      () => { this.control.setValue(value, {emitViewToModelChange: false}); });
}
```

So the setTimeout ensured that the input was selected after its view was updated.

If you want to avoid this asynchronous behavior, you can use `FormControl` instead of `ngModel` ([Demo StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11gpkn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)):

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<input #input [formControl]="count" />`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  private _item;

  @Input() set item(value) {
    this._item = value;
    this.count.setValue(value.count);
    this.focus();
  }

  get item() {
    return this._item;
  }

  @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;

  count = new FormControl();

  focus() {
    this.input.nativeElement.focus();
    this.input.nativeElement.select();
  }
}
```

With this approach, you don't need to call `focus()` explicitly from the parent component; the child component will call its own focus method whenever the input changes.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you trying to get an element before it has been rendered. That is impossible. 
I advice you to read about Lifecycle hooks in Angular. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

You can solve this problem, calling your foo() function in lifecycle hook - ngAfterViewInit.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.foo();
}
```

Comment: app-input-component is rendered but in foo I am changing the binding data